# How to show parents of current page category, excluding the category?

Tags: plugin-development, categories

I use this code to show the current page category parents, but I don't want it to include the current page category.

```
<?php echo get_category_parents( $cat, true, ' &raquo; ' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this, is by retrieving the direct parent of the current page category and then use [`get_category_parents`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_parents) on that category. Like this:

```
// supposing $cat contains the category ID
// load category object
$cat_obj = get_category ($cat);
// retrieve parent ID from object;
$parent = $cat_obj->parent;
// retrieve list of parent categories without current category
echo get_category_parents ($parent, true, ' &raquo; ');
```

(Untested but should work)